# Conditional dropdown depopulation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I have two dropdowns of numbers. The functionality I want is: when I choose an option out of the first list, compare that selected option's value with the second list's option values and hide any options in the second list that are greater than the first list's selected option value.

```
<select name="input_6" id="input_2_6" class="medium gfield_select" tabindex="13">
  <option value="117500">115,001 - 120,000</option>
  <option value="122500">120,001 - 125,000</option>
  <option value="127500">125,001 - 130,000</option>
  <option value="132500">130,001 - 135,000</option>
  <option value="137500">135,001 - 140,000</option>
  <option value="142500">140,001 - 145,000</option>
  <option value="147500">145,001 - 150,000</option>
  <option value="152500">150,001 - 155,000</option>
  <option value="157500">155,001 - 160,000</option>
  <option value="162500">160,001 - 165,000</option>
  <option value="167500">165,001 - 170,000</option>
  <option value="172500">170,001 - 175,000</option>
  <option value="177500">175,001 - 180,000</option>
  <option value="182500">180,001 - 185,000</option>
  <option value="187500">185,001 - 190,000</option>
  <option value="192500">190,001 - 195,000</option>
  <option value="197500">195,001 - 200,000</option>
  <option value="205000">200,001 - 210,000</option>
  <option value="215000">210,001 - 220,000</option>
  <option value="225000">220,001 - 230,000</option>
  <option value="235000">230,001 - 240,000</option>
  <option value="245000">240,001 - 250,000</option>
  <option value="255000" selected="selected">250,001 - 260,000</option>
  <option value="265000">260,001 - 270,000</option>
  <option value="275000">270,001 - 280,000</option>
  <option value="285000">280,001 - 290,000</option>
  <option value="295000">290,001 - 300,000</option>
  <option value="305000">300,001 - 310,000</option>
  <option value="315000">310,001 - 320,000</option>
  <option value="325000">320,001 - 330,000</option>
  <option value="335000">330,001 - 340,000</option>
  <option value="345000">340,001 - 350,000</option>
  <option value="355000">350,001 - 360,000</option>
</select>
<select name="input_7" id="input_2_7" class="medium gfield_select" tabindex="16">
  <option value="102500" selected="selected">100,000 - 105,000</option>
  <option value="107500">105,000 - 110,000</option>
  <option value="112500">110,000 - 115,000</option>
  <option value="117500">115,000 - 120,000</option>
  <option value="122500">120,000 - 125,000</option>
  <option value="127500">125,000 - 130,000</option>
  <option value="132500">130,000 - 135,000</option>
  <option value="137500">135,000 - 140,000</option>
  <option value="142500">140,000 - 145,000</option>
  <option value="147500">145,000 - 150,000</option>
  <option value="152500">150,000 - 155,000</option>
  <option value="157500">155,000 - 160,000</option>
  <option value="162500">160,000 - 165,000</option>
  <option value="167500">165,000 - 170,000</option>
  <option value="172500">170,000 - 175,000</option>
  <option value="177500">175,000 - 180,000</option>
  <option value="182500">180,000 - 185,000</option>
  <option value="187500">185,000 - 190,000</option>
  <option value="192500">190,000 - 195,000</option>
  <option value="197500">195,000 - 200,000</option>
  <option value="202500">200,000 - 205,000</option>
  <option value="207500">205,000 - 210,000</option>
  <option value="212500">210,000 - 215,000</option>
  <option value="217500">215,000 - 220,000</option>
  <option value="222500">220,000 - 225,000</option>
  <option value="227500">225,000 - 230,000</option>
  <option value="232500">230,000 - 235,000</option>
  <option value="237500">235,000 - 240,000</option>
  <option value="242500">240,000 - 245,000</option>
  <option value="247500">245,000 - 250,000</option>
  <option value="252500">250,000 - 255,000</option>
  <option value="257500">255,000 - 260,000</option>
  <option value="262500">260,000 - 265,000</option>
  <option value="267500">265,000 - 270,000</option>
  <option value="272500">270,000 - 275,000</option>
  <option value="277500">275,000 - 280,000</option>
  <option value="282500">280,000 - 285,000</option>
  <option value="287500">285,000 - 290,000</option>
  <option value="292500">290,000 - 295,000</option>
  <option value="297500">295,000 - 300,000</option>
  <option value="302500">300,000 - 305,000</option>
  <option value="307500">305,000 - 310,000</option>
  <option value="312500">310,000 - 315,000</option>
  <option value="317500">315,000 - 320,000</option>
  <option value="322500">320,000 - 325,000</option>
  <option value="327500">325,000 - 330,000</option>
  <option value="332500">330,000 - 335,000</option>
  <option value="337500">335,000 - 340,000</option>
  <option value="342500">340,000 - 345,000</option>
  <option value="347500">345,000 - 350,000</option>
  <option value="352500">350,000 - 355,000</option>
</select>
```

Above are the two lists I'm working with (generated by gravity forms).

And here are two variations of jQuery I've tried so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#input_2_6').change(function(){
    var initial = $('#input_2_6 option:selected').val();
    secondDropPop(initial);
    function secondDropPop(i){
        $('#input_2_7 option').each(function(){
            if ($(this).val() > i){
                $(this).css('display','none');
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

And

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#input_2_6').change(function(){
    $('#input_2_6 option').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':selected')){
            var initial = $(this).val();
            secondDropPop(initial);
        }
    });
    function secondDropPop(i){
        $('#input_2_7 option').each(function(){
            if ($(this).val() > i){
                $(this).css('display','none');
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

jQuery ver: 1.11.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [jQuery documention](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

> In the case of an array, the callback is passed an array index and a corresponding array value each time.

Looking at`$(this).val() > i`, `i` is not defined. This should be the first argument of your callback:

```
    $('#input_2_7 option').each(function(i){
        i = parseInt(i, 10);
        if (parseInt($(this).val(), 10) > i){
            $(this).css('display','none');
        }
    });
```

**Edit**

The problem here is that you are trying to apply styles to `option` tags which is a very unstable approach as each browser applies styles differently to `option` tags (some browsers do not allow any styles to apply). So your best bet is to create the second dropdown on the fly. Below is an example of this approach.

```js
$('#input_2_6').change(function(){
    var initial = $('#input_2_6 option:selected').val();
    secondDropPop(initial);
    function secondDropPop(i){
        $('#input_2_7 option').each(function(){
            if ($(this).val() > i){
                $(this).css('display','none');
            }
        });
    }
});

$('#input_2_6').change(function(){
    $('#input_2_6 option').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':selected')){
            var initial = $(this).val();
            secondDropPop(initial);
        }
    });
    function secondDropPop(i){
        var $dropdown = $('#input_2_7').hide();//hide the dropdown as this will prevent the browser from rendering every time an option is appended
        $dropdown.empty();
        $('#full_dropdown option').each(function(){
            if ($(this).val() <= i){
                $dropdown.append($(this).clone());
            }
        });
        $dropdown.show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="input_6" id="input_2_6" class="medium gfield_select" tabindex="13">
  <option value="117500">115,001 - 120,000</option>
  <option value="122500">120,001 - 125,000</option>
  <option value="127500">125,001 - 130,000</option>
  <option value="132500">130,001 - 135,000</option>
  <option value="137500">135,001 - 140,000</option>
  <option value="142500">140,001 - 145,000</option>
  <option value="147500">145,001 - 150,000</option>
  <option value="152500">150,001 - 155,000</option>
  <option value="157500">155,001 - 160,000</option>
  <option value="162500">160,001 - 165,000</option>
  <option value="167500">165,001 - 170,000</option>
  <option value="172500">170,001 - 175,000</option>
  <option value="177500">175,001 - 180,000</option>
  <option value="182500">180,001 - 185,000</option>
  <option value="187500">185,001 - 190,000</option>
  <option value="192500">190,001 - 195,000</option>
  <option value="197500">195,001 - 200,000</option>
  <option value="205000">200,001 - 210,000</option>
  <option value="215000">210,001 - 220,000</option>
  <option value="225000">220,001 - 230,000</option>
  <option value="235000">230,001 - 240,000</option>
  <option value="245000">240,001 - 250,000</option>
  <option value="255000" selected="selected">250,001 - 260,000</option>
  <option value="265000">260,001 - 270,000</option>
  <option value="275000">270,001 - 280,000</option>
  <option value="285000">280,001 - 290,000</option>
  <option value="295000">290,001 - 300,000</option>
  <option value="305000">300,001 - 310,000</option>
  <option value="315000">310,001 - 320,000</option>
  <option value="325000">320,001 - 330,000</option>
  <option value="335000">330,001 - 340,000</option>
  <option value="345000">340,001 - 350,000</option>
  <option value="355000">350,001 - 360,000</option>
</select>
<select name="input_7" id="input_2_7" class="medium gfield_select" tabindex="16" style="display:none">
</select>
<!--Create a new dropdown that is not used for anything except pulling data from. Turning this into an array could speed things up-->
<select id="full_dropdown" style="display:none;" tabindex="16">
  <option value="102500" selected="selected">100,000 - 105,000</option>
  <option value="107500">105,000 - 110,000</option>
  <option value="112500">110,000 - 115,000</option>
  <option value="117500">115,000 - 120,000</option>
  <option value="122500">120,000 - 125,000</option>
  <option value="127500">125,000 - 130,000</option>
  <option value="132500">130,000 - 135,000</option>
  <option value="137500">135,000 - 140,000</option>
  <option value="142500">140,000 - 145,000</option>
  <option value="147500">145,000 - 150,000</option>
  <option value="152500">150,000 - 155,000</option>
  <option value="157500">155,000 - 160,000</option>
  <option value="162500">160,000 - 165,000</option>
  <option value="167500">165,000 - 170,000</option>
  <option value="172500">170,000 - 175,000</option>
  <option value="177500">175,000 - 180,000</option>
  <option value="182500">180,000 - 185,000</option>
  <option value="187500">185,000 - 190,000</option>
  <option value="192500">190,000 - 195,000</option>
  <option value="197500">195,000 - 200,000</option>
  <option value="202500">200,000 - 205,000</option>
  <option value="207500">205,000 - 210,000</option>
  <option value="212500">210,000 - 215,000</option>
  <option value="217500">215,000 - 220,000</option>
  <option value="222500">220,000 - 225,000</option>
  <option value="227500">225,000 - 230,000</option>
  <option value="232500">230,000 - 235,000</option>
  <option value="237500">235,000 - 240,000</option>
  <option value="242500">240,000 - 245,000</option>
  <option value="247500">245,000 - 250,000</option>
  <option value="252500">250,000 - 255,000</option>
  <option value="257500">255,000 - 260,000</option>
  <option value="262500">260,000 - 265,000</option>
  <option value="267500">265,000 - 270,000</option>
  <option value="272500">270,000 - 275,000</option>
  <option value="277500">275,000 - 280,000</option>
  <option value="282500">280,000 - 285,000</option>
  <option value="287500">285,000 - 290,000</option>
  <option value="292500">290,000 - 295,000</option>
  <option value="297500">295,000 - 300,000</option>
  <option value="302500">300,000 - 305,000</option>
  <option value="307500">305,000 - 310,000</option>
  <option value="312500">310,000 - 315,000</option>
  <option value="317500">315,000 - 320,000</option>
  <option value="322500">320,000 - 325,000</option>
  <option value="327500">325,000 - 330,000</option>
  <option value="332500">330,000 - 335,000</option>
  <option value="337500">335,000 - 340,000</option>
  <option value="342500">340,000 - 345,000</option>
  <option value="347500">345,000 - 350,000</option>
  <option value="352500">350,000 - 355,000</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle without the `i` in passed into the `.each` function https://jsfiddle.net/zob68ron/1/ , which still does not work. Then we have this fiddle where I tested out your method, and I might be screwing something up, but I don't think this works either, https://jsfiddle.net/zob68ron/2/ .

Comment: This solution works beautifully. But once we hit values in the millions the functionality breaks. I've tried it both with and without the top function [here on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xseexjwz/). Why do you think this would be happening? @KJ Price  -  The thought is that they choose how much they paid for their home, then they choose how much they have left on their mortgage. That's why the numbers go up so high.

Comment: Ah, interesting. The problem there is that you are comparing strings to each other. So, "400" is actually *greater than* "1000000" when you are comparing strings (compares each individual character instead of magnitude of the number). You need to `parseInt` each of these values before comparing.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the `parseInt` comparison.